# Camera is not looping seamlessly

Tags: animation, camera

I have snapped the camera from point A to point B, the camera snapped exactly where the cursor was, and then I did, selection to cursor. The camera looks perfect from edge to edge. But when I click pay to view the animation, its not a perfect loop. I have included the file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set your *Array's Relative Offset* value to 1, it was set to 0.97 so it created a visual jump:

[image]

Also maybe apply the transforms, recreate the junction between start and end, put the 3D cursor on the end again and recreate the camera movement

Comment: OK, thanks for that point out.  The camera animation is fixed, but now that I have added a mesh circle in the background, it doesn't look seamlessly, what am I doing wrong? I added an additional file:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=SZJQ47Sb" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/SZJQ47Sb/)

Comment: well, if your circle doesn't move, seems logical that it jumps back after one loop, what you can do is move it as fast as the camera, for example you can parent it to the camera

Comment: I did it, but it seems that there's still a small glitch, I parented the circle to the camera and kept the transformation, so the circle is moving with the camera, but it looks like its skipping one frame. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=d2KMRlN3" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/d2KMRlN3/)

Comment: it looks like first and last image match so it may be a preview bug, try a render?